# Can I use CSS to override the disabling of autocomplete for a form, if so, how?

Tags: css, forms, browser, autocomplete, stylish

I am trying to use the chrome extension [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) to reenable autocomplete on forms that have it disabled.

Specifically, the form has it disabled by specifying `autocomplete="off"` and I want it re-enabled.

I tried using this:

`form { autocomplete: on;}`

and variations of it, but it does not work. I'm not sure if this is even an attribute you can override via CSS, let alone how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

CSS affects what's inside `style` properties, and some of the old attributes (length/cellpadding/color etc).  autocomplete is not one of those.  JS is the right way.
Something on the lines of:

```
documnet.getElementById('element_id').autocomplete='on';
```

Comment: autocomplete is a new property: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_attributes.asp

Comment: Also, what if I don't know the element id?

Comment: it is a form attribute, not CSS attribute. As for the second comment, If I understand your purpose, then just write a JS that catches ALL forms in a page, use `getElementsByTagName('form') or `window.forms` (I think, check this).

Answer (score 1):

I installed [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), and used it to figure out the syntax, then wrote a crude script for [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Yes, those are for different browsers. I wanted this to work in Chrome, but knew firebug would be a quick way to figure out and test the syntax.):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Autocomplete Enabler
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @include    http://*/*
// @include    https://*/*
// @copyright  2011+, You
// ==/UserScript==
var formcount=0;
var i=0;

for (i=0;i<=formcount;i++)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('form')[i].setAttribute('autocomplete','on');
}
```

It worked, at least for my bank's website. I'll save form information if I want to!

Answer (score 0):

You could write an [userscript](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts) to do that.

Comment: But it's still a solution to the problem at hand. Also... your solution is an userscript. What gives?